# Adding an RBAC Owner admin for a subscription with Graph or Azure AD Graph

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator#add-an-rbac-owner-admin-for-a-subscription-in-azure-portal) describes how to add user in a owner role to particular subscription. But can it be done from code? Preferably using Azure SDK .Net (Microsoft.Graph package) or by Azure AD Graph (Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent package).

Comment: `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` is not Azure AD Graph API, it is a library for the Azure Management API. And that is what you are after. MS Graph and Azure AD Graph cannot do that.

Comment: When i inspected Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent objects under debugger i found reference to graph.windows.net url so I assumed it has something to do with it.

Comment: From what i have played with *.Fluent package it seems like there is no way to invite external user (by providing his email) - which prevents me from assigning him an admin role.
I figured that i need Graph or Azure AD Graph to do it but there are literally no examples on the net and i'm very confused right now.

Comment: You never said "external user" :) Yeah, that user you first have to add through Azure AD Graph/MS Graph (if it is possible to invite guests through there) and then use the Azure Management API to add them to a role

Comment: Please note that Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph are two different APIs sets.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the above comments .You can [create invitation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post) using Microsoft Graph api to create a new invitation. Invitation adds an external user to the organization. Then you can [manage Role-Based Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest) with the Azure Resource Manager API .

To call Microsoft Graph, your app must acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory , please click [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) for tutorial and code sample .

Since Microsoft Graph api and  Azure Resource Manager API are different endpoint/resource . You need to acquire two different tokens because you cannot use the same access token against another resource .